# Layout go up when keyboard is open in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard, android-edittext

I want to move the layout up when the soft keyboard is open. I tried with all the options that I found in Google like

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

but my layout does not move up.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: what about `adjustResize`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

**"adjustResize"**

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard on screen.

**"adjustPan"**

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your manifest file

```
<application ... >
<activity
    android:name=".myActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
    ...
</activity>
...
</application>
```